# data structure with vectors as elements in R

Tags: r

I need to plot a large number of graphs from the same data frame.
each plot describes a different group of variables in the data frame, but each variable is contained in several plots.
My plan is to loop through a data structure which would include the name for each graph, and the vector of variables indexes to plot.

for example:

| plot names | range | other parameters |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ICC - 1 | c(1:20) | 1 |
| IIC - 2 | c(10:30) | 2 |
| TCC - 1b | c(20:40) | 1 |
| TIC - 2x | c(20:40) | 4 |

However, I can't find a suitable data structure in R, in which one column would contain the list of plot names (strings) and the second column would be a list of variable ranges (vectors).
additional column might contain other parameters for each plot.

So,

1. Is there a suitable data structure in R?
2. Is there a better way to go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is *list-columns*. It's a little difficult to build them from the start, but not so hard to add them later.

```r
### won't work
dat <- data.frame(a=c("ICC-1","IIC-2"), range=list(1:10, 10:30))
# Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
#   arguments imply differing number of rows: 10, 21

### this does work
dat <- data.frame(a=c("ICC-1","IIC-2"))
dat$range <- list(1:10, 10:30)
dat
#       a                                                                              range
# 1 ICC-1                                                      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
# 2 IIC-2 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30
```

(It is feasible to add `1:10` as a quoted expression if you'd prefer, but that takes more care in follow-on processing that I did not want to assume.)

Comment: Thanks! Haven't embedded it completely but it seems to work perfectly!